# WAMP Virtual Hosts Setup

Tags: wamp

**Problem**

I had WAMP running happily and decided to set up Virtual Hosts. Now WAMP won’t start (stuck on orange). There is no error log because Apache won’t start.

Also relevant: this version of WAMP listens on port 81 and MySQL uses port 3307.

**Request**

I have been at this for hours and cannot see my mistake. I’d be grateful if anyone can spot it.

**Apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts**

```
NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ## Using Apache 2.4 syntax
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        Require local
        ## And possibly allow access from your local network
        ## Check you subnet for the actual values to use here
        Require ip 192.168.0
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Jo/My Websites/Demonstrations"
    ServerName demonstrations.com
    ServerAlias www.demonstrations.com
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    ## Using Apache 2.4 syntax
    <Directory "C:/Users/Jo/My Websites/Demonstrations">
       AllowOverride All
       Require local
       #If you want to allow access from your internal network
       # For specific ip addresses add one line per ip address
       #Require ip 192.168.0.nnn
       # For every ip in the subnet, just use the first 3 numbers of the subnet
       #Require ip 192.168.0
       # If you want to allow access to everyone
       #Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache/conf/http.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require local

</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/Jo/My Websites/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1:81
</Directory>
```

AND

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts.txt**

```
127.0.0.1:81      localhost:81
127.0.0.1:81      demonstrators.com  #Site for demos
```

If anyone can spot my mistake, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

First remove this entry in the httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:/Users/Jo/My Websites/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1:81
</Directory>
```

Its unnecessary as this is dont in the `httpd-vhost.conf` file, but also you cannot use a port number on that command

Then change your host file to

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      demonstrators.com  #Site for demos
::1  localhost
::1  demonstrators.com
```

Again ports are not used on these statements.

Once these are changed try starting Apache again.

If it fails to start this is a useful method of finding errors in the Apache config.

Start a command window, and CD to the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` folder

Run this command

```
httpd -t
```

This will validate your httpd.conf and any other files that it includes and report the line number where the error is.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly - who for newbies arriving is the guru at WampServer - look for his instructions.  I will experiment with each.