# WAMP: Virtual Host for apache 2.4.9

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

I have created `virtual host` in `WAMP` but browser is always looking for live site. I have commented virtual host line from `httpd.conf` and my http-vhost file looks like

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
   ServerName localhost
   <Directory "D:/wamp/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/ltl"
  ServerName ltl_new.local
  ServerAlias ltl_new.local
  ErrorLog "logs/mysilverstripe.log"
  <Directory "D:/Projects/ltl">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require local
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

And entries in host file looks like

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 ::1        localhost

 127.0.0.1       ltl_new.local
::1     ltl_new.local
```

But when I try to access `ltl_new.local` it gives me server not found and browser url becomes `www.ltl_new.local`. The `apache version is 2.4.9`. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113258/wamp-virtual-host-not-working) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006008/wamp-virtual-hosts-setup) and many other related questions but couldn't be able to resolve my problem.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `_` (underscores) in a domain name, the underscore is not an allowed character in a domain name.

If you remove the `_` in both the HOSTS file and the Virtual Hosts Definition file `httpd-vhosts.conf` then everything should work as otherwise everything looks OK.